# Sanitizing HTML output in templates in 2.4

Tags: template, security, magento2.4

Before 2.4 the way you could sanitize an html value in a template was to use `$block->escapeHtml($valueHere);`.
Where `$blick` is the instance of the current block.
This still works in 2.4, but the method is deprecated.

```
/**
 * Escape HTML entities
 *
 * @param string|array $data
 * @param array|null $allowedTags
 * @return string
 * @deprecated Use $escaper directly in templates and in blocks.
 */
public function escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    return $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
}
```

The recommendation is to use the escaper directly in the templates.
But I cannot add the escaper instance as a view model in the template because `Magento\Framework\Escaper` does not implement `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface`.
So if I do this in my layout files

```
<block ...>
    <arguments>
        <argument name="escaper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Escaper</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I get an exception

> Instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface is expected, got Magento\Framework\Escaper instead.

Is there another clean way to use escape the html values in a template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 2.4 simply calling `$escaper->escapeHtml()` works.
`$escaper` is an instance of `Magento\Framework\Escaper` sent directly to the template in the same way as `$block` is an instance of the current block class.  It's all done in `Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render()`

```
public function render(BlockInterface $block, $fileName, array $dictionary = [])
{
    ob_start();
    try {
        $tmpBlock = $this->_currentBlock;
        $this->_currentBlock = $block;
        extract($dictionary, EXTR_SKIP);
        //So it can be used in the template.
        $escaper = $this->escaper; // <-- here it is
        // phpcs:ignore
        include $fileName;
        $this->_currentBlock = $tmpBlock;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        ob_end_clean();
        throw $exception;
    }
    /** Get output buffer. */
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Weirdly it doesn't seem to be in the release notes but it is in the dev docs. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html

Comment: Kind of stupid that there is no Getter to access this variable inside Blocks.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to access it via EVERY block. If you need it in the template, it's there. If you need it in a block class you inject it as a dependency