# Undefined variable: escaper (Magento 2 @var syntax)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

I have a theme I purchased from ThemeForest, but they are not being helpful (they don't understand english much!)

My question in terms of **loading Classes are based on the following:**

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image */
/** @var $escaper \Magento\Framework\Escaper */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
/**
 * Enable lazy loading for images with borders and if variable enable_lazy_loading_for_images_w>
 * is enabled in view.xml. Otherwise small size images without borders may be distorted. So max>
 * to prevent stretching and lazy loading does not work.
 */
$borders = (bool)$block->getVar('product_image_white_borders', 'Magento_Catalog');
```

The 'commented' `@var syntax` as inside there, is Magento 2 supposed to 'autoload' those class definitions/files?

This is the error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: escaper in 
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml on line 35
```

Line 35:

```
<img class="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getClass()) ?>
```

I am trying to figure out why they used 'commented `@var` entries', and why `Escaper` is undefined.
*Interestingly, `$block` as image does not fail* a few lines upwards: (line 15)

```
$block->getVar('product_image_white_borders', 'Magento_Catalog');`
```

It feels more like `Magento\Framework` is not loaded, I see no module `Magento_Framework` for instance. NOTE: *I assume Framework is loaded differently by Magento 2, but I can't verify if it working or not!*

This must be something not loaded, because they use `@var` definitions in alot of their templates.

#### Extra info

I have already run

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade && \
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB en_US && bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Please assist, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the theme you bought is for magento 2.4
You can see more details in this question and  answer: [Sanitizing HTML output in templates in 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/316854/146) and in the official documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html

If you want to make it work for 2.3, you can replace in all the templates `$escaper->...` with `$block->....`

Comment: They did update it for Magento 2.4, but claimed that it works with Magento 2.3.5.   Thanks this makes sense, now how do I explain this to them!!!!

Comment: However, there is an `Magento\Framework\Escaper.php` file in my Magento 2.3.5 installation?

Comment: Tell them it doesn't work with 2.3 and also show them the differences between https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html

Comment: @CvRChameleon. Yes, there is an escaper file and class. the class is not new. it has been there for a while. it is just not available in the templates for versions before 2.4. Read the question and the answer in the first link for more info

Comment: Thanks for the quick clarification!  I will tell them that it does not work.  Luckily I have the older version downloaded as well - pre2.4 downloaded (never used it).

Answer (score 0):

Purchased themes for M2 generally aren't a good idea, in my opinion.

The comments don't autoload anything. They are only there to signal your IDE which classes the objects have, so the IDE can suggest methods you can use when programming.

The error simply means that the theme has a bug.

To solve it in this particular case, you may be able to replace `$escaper` with `$block`. It should work.

Comment: Interesting that you say they don't autoload :( . I wonder why they did that, it's done in several files!  Then I assume `$block` is then populated upwards in the call stack trace? As in populated in some other `PHP File`?  So I need to initialize the `Magento\Framework\Escaper   $escaper` file myself?

Comment: Yes, $block is generally available in template files and populated a few calls above that. I explained why they did that: it’s for the IDE

Comment: Thanks :)  Marius pointed out is a difference between Magento2.3 and Magento 2.4, however when I purchased the theme they claimed this version works with M2.3, M2.4.  I am glad that I do not bother upgrading to 2.4 yet - its vastly different.

Comment: Typically, Marius knows more about things than me :) So I would assume he is right. Their claim is just another reason I wouldn’t buy any theme for M2

Comment: Haha :)  Yes I actually tried to make sure to find a `2.3.5` compatible theme, time is restricted when I have to handle everything - docker, server configuration, data migration from M1 (NIGHTMARE!!!!) etc